# Programmatically Rotating Cube by using timer in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

i have created cube like below  and rotate it by using scroll. I need to rotate it programmatically when a button a click by using timer.How can i do it?

```
<DockPanel Margin="0" >


        <ScrollBar Name="hscroll" 
          DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
          Orientation="Horizontal" 
          Minimum="-180" Maximum="180" 
          LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" Value="0" />
        <ScrollBar Name="vscroll" 
          DockPanel.Dock="Right"
          Orientation="Vertical"
          Minimum="-180" Maximum="180" 
          LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" Value="0" />

        <!--
           - The dockOuter control prevents the rendering
           - from including an implicit margin around dockCube
          -->
        <DockPanel Margin="0" Name="dockOuter" Background="White">
            <DockPanel Margin="0" Name="dockCube" Background="White">
                <Viewport3D Margin="0" Name="viewCube">
                    <ModelVisual3D>
                        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                            <Model3DGroup>
                                <!-- Lights -->
                                <AmbientLight Color="Gray" />
                                <DirectionalLight Color="Gray" Direction="1,-2,-3" />
                                <DirectionalLight Color="Gray" Direction="-1,2,3" />

                                <!-- Top -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "-1,1,1 1,1,1 1,1,-1 -1,1,-1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0 1 2     2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Top.png"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- Front -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "-1,-1,1 1,-1,1 1,1,1 -1,1,1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0 1 2     2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Front.png"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- Right -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "1,-1,1 1,-1,-1 1,1,-1 1,1,1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0 1 2     2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Right.png"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- Left -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "-1,-1,-1 -1,-1,1 -1,1,1 -1,1,-1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0 1 2     2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Left.png"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- Back -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "1,-1,-1 -1,-1,-1 -1,1,-1 1,1,-1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0 1 2     2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Back.png"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                                <!-- Bottom -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D
                                            Positions = "-1,-1,-1 1,-1,-1 1,-1,1 -1,-1,1"
                                            TriangleIndices = "0 1 2     2,3,0"
                                            TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Bottom.png"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>

                            </Model3DGroup>
                        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    </ModelVisual3D>

                    <Viewport3D.Camera>
                        <PerspectiveCamera
                          Position = "3, 3, 3"
                          LookDirection = "-1, -1, -1"
                          UpDirection = "0, 1, 0"
                          FieldOfView = "60">
                            <PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
                                <Transform3DGroup>
                                    <RotateTransform3D>
                                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                            <AxisAngleRotation3D
                                              Axis="0 1 0" 
                                              Angle="{Binding ElementName=hscroll, Path=Value}" />
                                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    </RotateTransform3D>
                                    <RotateTransform3D>
                                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                            <AxisAngleRotation3D
                                              Axis="1 0 0" 
                                              Angle="{Binding ElementName=vscroll, Path=Value}" />
                                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    </RotateTransform3D>
                                </Transform3DGroup>
                            </PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
                        </PerspectiveCamera>
                    </Viewport3D.Camera>
                </Viewport3D>
            </DockPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using WPF in a non-trivial way, I'm going to assume you are familiar with (and using) the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern. If not, look it up, it's the best way to manage WPF applications.

Currently, your camera rotation is bound to the scrollbars value. So to be nitpicky, your cube stays the same, but your camera is rotating around it, making it look as if your cube were rotating. To influence this from code, first create two properties in your viewmodel and bind your scrollbar values to those properties. Then bind your rotation to those values instead of directly to the scrollbar. Nothing has changed so far, when you test it, your application should work the same as before. But now you have two variables in your program that you can set by code. For example incrementing them on the Tick event of a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) instance in your viewmodel.

Please note that WPF normally uses [StoryBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx)s for animation, that can be used in XAML without C# code.